# Craftnet API package query

Tags: plugin-development, composer, api

Does querying composer packages via the Craftnet API need authentication?
Ref https://docs.api.craftcms.com/packages.html

Querying the Craft CMS package itself is fine, eg https://api.craftcms.com/v1/package/craftcms/cms. However trying to query any plugins is throwing a 404, eg https://api.craftcms.com/v1/package/craftcms/contact-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug with package names that contained `-`s. Just fixed that, so `/v1/package/craftcms/contact-form` works now.

Comment: Great, thanks Brandon!